# Run multiple commands and consolidate exit codes

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a script which runs multiple commands and I want to return a 0 exit code if all is well, 1 if not. In the first iteration, my script looks like this:

```bash
make foo
make bar
```

The problem is, if `make foo` failed, my script does not return an exit code of 1 because that exit code was overwritten by `make bar`, which passed.

Second iteration:

```
RC=0
make foo || RC=1
make bar || RC=1
exit $RC
```

This works, but it is cumbersome. Is there a better way?

## Update

To clarify, I want to run **all** the commands no matter what. So, if `make foo` failed, I still want to run `make bar` after that. This is part of a pipeline, so I want to run all commands, only to return the code at the end where 0=OK, 1=Some command failed.

Comment: `make foo && make bar` will exit if `make foo` fails before attempting `make bar`. You can also simply capture the exit codes in an array, e.g. `declare -a errcodes` and then `make foo; errcodes+=($?)` and the same for `make bar`. You can then output the results before ending the script with `declare -p errcodes`.

Comment: Why would you want the script to continue if something failed? What would an ambiguous  non-zero exit status that doesn't return a specific status or error on standard error actually accomplish for you?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs It's not that strange. The individual commands might be independent and idempotent, meaning it's safe to rerun the same script repeatedly until all commands succeed.

Comment: Thank you all for asking, I have posted an update to my question.

Comment: Second option in my comment will work. `declare -a errcodes; make foo; errcodes+=($?); make bar; errcodes+=($?); declare -p errcodes` could be your entire script. If `make foo` fails and `make bar` succeeds, your output would be `declare -a errcodes=([0]="1" [1]="0")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ERR` trap to update the value of `RC` if a command fails.

```
trap 'RC=1' ERR

...

exit $RC
```

If `RC` never gets set, making the final command `exit` with no argument, the exit status of the last command is used, but that's 0 by virtue of the trap never being triggered.

Comment: This is just what the doctor ordered. Thank you.