# Makefile: Execute several commands, ignore errors and return exit code

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile in which I would like to run several commands and ignore error. However, the make target will fail if one of the commands fail. I am running this Makefile on Mac, Ubuntu, and Redhat, so the versions of `make` are different. I believe the lowest version is 3.8.

Currently, my solution is:

```
target:
    RC1=0; RC2=0; RC3=0; \
    command1; \
    RC1=$$?; \
    command1=2; \
    RC2=$$?; \
    command3; \
    RC3=$$?; \
    if [ $$RC1 -ne 0 ] || [ $$RC2 -ne 0 ] || [ $$R3 -ne 0 ]; then \
          RC=1; \
    fi; \
    exit $$RC
```

The problem is at the end with the `if` statement: Later, I might insert more commands, `command4`, `command5`, ... and the `if` statement will be very clunkly. Is there a simpler solution?

I wish if I can do something like this:

```
target:
    -command1
    -command2
    -command3
    # Exit with non-zero code if one of the command failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any point in keeping all these individual error codes.  Why  not just use:

```
target:
        RC=0; \
        command1 || RC=1; \
        command1 || RC=1; \
        command3 || RC=1; \
        exit $$RC
```

I can't think of a simpler way than that though.

Comment: Just to point out this isn't really a makefile problem: it's a shell scripting problem.

Comment: If it is a shell problem, I was given a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72999401/run-multiple-commands-and-consolidate-exit-codes) already.

Comment: This will work. Thank you @MadScientist

Comment: The only thing that is unique to the makefile is you need it to be all in one logical line, with the semicolon and backslash... but you already knew that part, based on your question.  There's not fancier way to do this in a makefile recipe than there is in a shell script... because a makefile recipe _IS_ a shell script.

Comment: There isn't any built-in facility to make like the `-` prefix, that means "ignore this error and run the rest of the commands, but still eventually fail the recipe".  That is something that's so rarely needed that there's no special facility for it.